# LNK1104 error with python setup.py build

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x, quantlib

I have built Quantlib on Windows using Visual Studio 2017 and want to build Quantlib-SWIG for Python.

However, I have LNK1104: error. Namely, after launching `Command Prompt` from `C:\QuantLib-SWIG-1.12\Python` directory I receive this error:

```
 fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'QuantLib-vc90-x64-mt.lib'
```

I saw a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390005/python-setup-py-build-gives-link1104-error) question with advise from Luigi Ballabio and KingJohnno to verify if `QuantLib-vc90-x64-mt.lib` file is in place & add to the path variable `C:\QuantLib-SWIG-1.12`.

I did the last suggestion, but I have the problem with that I have in `C:\QuantLib\QuantLib-1.12\lib` a `QuantLib-vc141-x64-mt.lib` library, i.e. not the file `QuantLib-vc90-x64-mt.lib`. I have created separate directory with vc141 file renamed to vc90. This did not help.

I have also read online that the problem might be with the Python specifically builded using different VS version. I have downloaded Python 2.7 builded using VS 2010 (not VS2008) and did not succeed as well.

Please see the whole terminal message here:

```
C:\QuantLib-SWIG-1.12\Python>cd C:\QuantLib-SWIG-1.12\Python

C:\QuantLib-SWIG-1.12\Python>set QL_DIR=C:\QuantLib\QuantLib-1.12

C:\QuantLib-SWIG-1.12\Python>set INCLUDE=C:\Boost\boost_1_66_0

C:\QuantLib-SWIG-1.12\Python>
C:\QuantLib-SWIG-1.12\Python>python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'QuantLib._QuantLib' extension
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -D__WIN32__ -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_WINDOWS -DNOMINMAX -IC:\Python27vc08\include -IC:\Python27vc08\PC -IC:\QuantLib\QuantLib-1.12 -IC:\Boost\boost_1_66_0 /TpQuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.obj /GR /FD /Zm250 /EHsc /bigobj /MD
quantlib_wrap.cpp
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\xutility(2472) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
        C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\xutility(2485) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Copy_opt<_InIt,unsigned int*,std::forward_iterator_tag>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,_InOutItCat,std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag,std::_Range_checked_iterator_tag)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _OutIt=unsigned int *,
            _InIt=const unsigned __int64 *,
            _InOutItCat=std::forward_iterator_tag
        ]
        C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\xutility(2563) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Copy_opt<const unsigned __int64*,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::random_access_iterator_tag,std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag,std::_Range_checked_iterator_tag)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _OutIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vbase,std::allocator<std::_Vbase>>,
            _InIt=const unsigned __int64 *
        ]
        QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp(16340) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc> std::copy<std::_Vector_const_iterator<unsigned __int64,std::allocator<unsigned __int64>>,std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=std::_Vbase,
            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Vbase>,
            _InIt=std::_Vector_const_iterator<size_t,std::allocator<size_t>>,
            _OutIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vbase,std::allocator<std::_Vbase>>
        ]
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Python27vc08\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python27vc08\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Python27vc08\PC\VS9.0\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\QuantLib\QuantLib-1.12\lib /EXPORT:init_QuantLib build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\QuantLib\_QuantLib.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\QuantLib\_QuantLib.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\QuantLib\_QuantLib.pyd.manifest /subsystem:windows /machine:x64
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'QuantLib-vc90-x64-mt.lib'
error: command 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104

C:\QuantLib-SWIG-1.12\Python>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python setup.py build` worked under `Python 3.6.5`.